# Ionic 5 export file to www during build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm developing an app which will be used by different companies. Each company should have their own app with different environment variables. Therefore, I got files named "env.js" similar to the following for each company:

```
window.companyName = 'abc';
window.apiUrl='http://localhost:8080/api/';
window.theme='abc';
```

At compile time, I'm setting an environment variable using `set APP_BUILDENV=acb`.
Then, I'm hooking into ionics build:before and serve:before hooks to execute a script that copies the "env.js" file to the www directory. In index.html I include env.js as a script:

```
<script src="env.js"></script>
```

However, the devserver redirects the call to env.js to index.html so that the environment data is not loaded. How can I allow the browser to access the env.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now exporting env.js to a directory named "config" and added the following to projects -> app -> architect -> build -> options in angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
   {
     "input": "config/env.js"
   }
 ]
```